# Read resources in annotation processor with kotlin and kapt

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kapt

I want to use an annotation processor that needs to read files from `src/main/resources` during the processing. It works fine with the following configuration when using java as a source:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.sourcepath = files("src/main/resources")
}
```

I´m now trying to use the same annotation processor with kotlin and kapt, it however always fails with a  file not found exception.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':cap-crd:kaptKotlin'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource-operation.vm
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource-operation.vm
at io.sundr.transform.internal.VelocityTransformationProcessor.process(VelocityTransformationProcessor.java:128)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:972)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource-operation.vm
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.getResource(JavacFiler.java:586)
at io.sundr.transform.internal.VelocityTransformationProcessor.readTemplate(VelocityTransformationProcessor.java:223)
at io.sundr.transform.internal.VelocityTransformationProcessor.process(VelocityTransformationProcessor.java:124)
... 50 more
```

So far I did not find the equivalent configuration for options.sourcepath with kotlin/kapt in order for the annotation processor to be able to access the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the following kapt config

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("--source-path", file("src/main/resources").absolutePath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `resource-operation.vm` under `src/main/resources`make sure to reference it using `/resource-operation.vm`